# -bash: pod: command not found

Tags: bash, terminal, cocoapods, podfile

I am taking a course from Udemy for iOS 10 (swift 3) programming. An app works with Firebase and Firebase requires a pod file. In the course, it said to type the following commands in Terminal to install a pod:

```
          cd Desktop/
          ln
          cd dc-social
          ln
          pod init
```

But when I run the pod init command, it gives me an error:

```
      -bash: pod: command not found
```

I am running macOS Sierra (the final release). What should I do? Any help would be appreciated :)
Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps need to install https://cocoapods.org/app

Comment: @cloud1 thanks for helping but it still isn't working. I try to install the command line interface but CocoaPods asks me for my password but it doesn't install it for some reason. Can you help me here?

Comment: I have taken the same course and have the same problem. Someone please help!

Comment: I had the same problem, you need to install cocoapods into your project directory. Check this link, this could solve my problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXLyB9NVouk

Answer (score 8):

try to run this first
(it will ask your admin password)

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was unable to install with gem (`sudo gem install cocoapods`) but successfully installed with homebrew:

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same course and got the same problem. I found out that we have to install `cocapods` before we run that command. So do the following in your terminal (it will ask for your password):

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

This will install some stuff and then you will be able to run the "init pod command".

Comment: I believe this suggestion has already been made, and OP said it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late, but often you can't do a sudo when your not an admin.
Then do this, open the terminal. Change to an admin user with

```
su 'theadminName'
```

Type the admin password. 
Then do

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```